# Jpa transaction javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I've got an application that's doing a bunch of writes to various database tables via jpa.  One of those writes can cause an optimistic lock exception. If one is thrown, it's not a big deal and I want the rest of the transaction to commit.

I took a look at the no-rollback functionality on the spring transaction via:

```
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="ignoreOptimisticLockingExceptionRule"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ignoreOptimisticLockingExceptionRule" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute">
    <property name="rollbackRules">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NoRollbackRuleAttribute">
                <constructor-arg value="javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

My app catches the OLException around the merge method of the entity that will throw this exception, but the transaction still gets rolled back.  I did some digging around to see what was up, and in the doCommit method of JpaTransactionManager is where javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly  gets thrown.  It gets thrown because the rollbackOnly flag (in TransactionImpl) was marked as true.

Digging deeper into that, i see that merge method in AbstractEntityMangerImpl ultimately marks the transaction as rollbackonly  which then triggers the exception further up.  I don't see where the RuleBasedTransactionAttributes get applied though.  I don't know if i have that setup properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JPA specification mandates that the transaction is marked for rollback when an OptimisticLockException occurs. And I don't know which JPA engine you use, but at least for Hibernate (and I would expect the same thing for other engines), the documentation says:

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not
>   leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by
>   Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will
>   be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

So if you get such an exception, your best bet is to let the transaction rollback, and retry.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit of a bummer. So my options are basically to redo everything because a secondary table I don't really care about has more current information, or separate the two. Thanks for the information. I think I have an alternate workaround (it's batching logic and there is a stale object that is causing the problem).  Thanks!