# Strange behaviour with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, rollback

**Here is my problem :**

I'm running a batch on a Java EE/Spring/Hibernate application. This batch calls a `method1`. This method calls a `method2` which can throw `UserException` (a class extending `RuntimeException`). Here is how it looks like :

```
@Transactional
public class BatchService implements IBatchService {
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public User method2(User user) {
   // Processing, which can throw a RuntimeException
 }

 public void method1() {
   // ...
   try {
     this.method2(user);
   } catch (UserException e) {
     // ...
   }
   // ...
 }
}
```

The exception is catched as the execution continues, but at the end of `method1` when the transaction is closed a RollbackException is thrown.

**Here is the stack trace :**

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy128.method1(Unknown Source)
at batch.BatchController.method1(BatchController.java:202)
```

When `method2` is not throwing this exception, it works well.

**What I have tried:**

- Setting `@Transactional(noRollbackFor={UserException.class}))` on `method1`
- Try and catch in `method2`

But it didn't change anything.

As the exception is thrown in a different transaction where a rollback happened I don't understand why it doesn't work. I had a look at this : [Jpa transaction javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418290/jpa-transaction-javax-persistence-rollbackexception-transaction-marked-as-rollb) but it didn't really help me.

I will be very greatful if someone could give me a clue.

**Update**

I've made it work by setting `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` on the method called by `method2` (which is actually the one which is sending the exception). This method is defined in a class very similar to my `BatchService`. So I don't see why it works on this level and not on `method2`.

- I've set `method2` as public as the annotation `@Transactional` is not taken into account if the method is private as said in the documentation :

> The @Transactional annotation may be placed before an interface
>   definition, a method on an interface, a class definition, or a public
>   method on a class.

- I also tried to use `Exception` instead of `RuntimeException` (as it is more appropriate) but it also didn't change anything.

Even if it is working the question remains open as it has a strange behaviour and I would like to understand why it's not acting like it should be.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152686/self-injection-with-spring/ for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Spring transactions, by default, work by wrapping the Spring bean with a proxy which handles the transaction and the exceptions. When you call `method2()` from `method1()`, you're completely bypassing this proxy, so it can't start a new transaction, and you're effectively calling `method2()` from the same transaction as the one opened by the call to `method1()`.

On the contrary, when you call a method of another injected bean from `method1()`, you're in fact calling a method on a transactional proxy. So if this alien method is marked with REQUIRES_NEW, a new transaction is started by the proxy, and you're able to catch the exception in `method1()` and resume the outer transaction.

This is described in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained).

Comment: Perfect answer with a real understanding of what is happening, Thank you !

Comment: Note that if you need these self invocations to work, you should use AspectJ mode in Spring. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html: "Consider the use of AspectJ mode (see mode attribute in table below) if you expect self-invocations to be wrapped with transactions as well. In this case, there will not be a proxy in the first place; instead, the target class will be weaved (that is, its byte code will be modified) in order to turn @Transactional into runtime behavior on any kind of method."

Comment: yeah,real understanding of the spring transaction... thank you